# libgfortran not found when installing scipy using enthought canopy

Tags: python, scipy, pip, enthought

I am trying to install scipy using `enpkg` in Enthought Canopy but I am getting this error:

```
(canopy_env) server 17:10:33 ~ $ enpkg scipy
prefix: /home/user/apps/canopy_env
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/apps/canopy_env/bin/enpkg", line 10, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/home/user/apps/Canopy/appdata/canopy-1.1.0.1371.rh5-x86_64/lib/python2.7/site-packages/enstaller/main.py", line 746, in main
    install_req(enpkg, req, args)             # install (default)
  File "/home/user/apps/Canopy/appdata/canopy-1.1.0.1371.rh5-x86_64/lib/python2.7/site-packages/enstaller/main.py", line 395, in install_req
    _perform_install()
  File "/home/user/apps/Canopy/appdata/canopy-1.1.0.1371.rh5-x86_64/lib/python2.7/site-packages/enstaller/main.py", line 311, in _perform_install
    enpkg.execute(actions)
  File "/home/user/apps/Canopy/appdata/canopy-1.1.0.1371.rh5-x86_64/lib/python2.7/site-packages/enstaller/enpkg.py", line 279, in execute
    self.fetch(egg, force=int(opcode[-1]))
  File "/home/user/apps/Canopy/appdata/canopy-1.1.0.1371.rh5-x86_64/lib/python2.7/site-packages/enstaller/enpkg.py", line 455, in fetch
    f.fetch_egg(egg, force, self._execution_aborted)
  File "/home/user/apps/Canopy/appdata/canopy-1.1.0.1371.rh5-x86_64/lib/python2.7/site-packages/enstaller/fetch.py", line 147, in fetch_egg
    self.fetch(egg, execution_aborted)
  File "/home/user/apps/Canopy/appdata/canopy-1.1.0.1371.rh5-x86_64/lib/python2.7/site-packages/enstaller/fetch.py", line 30, in fetch
    fi, info = self.remote.get(key)
  File "/home/user/apps/Canopy/appdata/canopy-1.1.0.1371.rh5-x86_64/lib/python2.7/site-packages/enstaller/store/indexed.py", line 47, in get
    return self.get_data(key), self.get_metadata(key)
  File "/home/user/apps/Canopy/appdata/canopy-1.1.0.1371.rh5-x86_64/lib/python2.7/site-packages/enstaller/store/indexed.py", line 136, in get_data
    raise KeyError("%s: %s" % (e, url))
KeyError: u'HTTP Error 404: NOT FOUND: https://api.enthought.com/eggs/rh5-64/libgfortran-3.0.0-1.egg'
```

I am using Canopy Express and this package is provided (see [this](https://www.enthought.com/products/canopy/package-index/))..
I have tried to install it from pip but, since I have not administration permissions, I am unable to install it..

Edit: the same happens with Pygments package when installing ipython:

```
appinst-2.1.2-1.egg                                                [fetching]
    55 KB [.................................................................]
MarkupSafe-0.18-2.egg                                              [fetching]
    26 KB [.................................................................]
...
KeyError: u'HTTP Error 404: NOT FOUND: https://api.enthought.com/eggs/rh5-64/Pygments-1.6.0-1.egg'
```

Thanks

Comment: Hi Francesco, we're fixing this issue, hang in there!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a few of our free packages had been flagged as "commercial" by mistake. We fixed the problem and you should be able to install them now.

Sorry about the trouble!